OPC UA Hello World to Codesys soft PLC failing
I am trying to create a Hello World app with C# and OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua to connect to a Codesys software PLC that is up and running.  I have not found enough documentation about the Opc.Ua package to really understand all the nuances.  I can finally create a session, but when I try to open it I get a "BadConnectionClosed" exception.  I don't know what tools I can use to track this down.  Any pointers to documentation or debugging suggestions will be welcome.  My code follows:
public class OPCAgent
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        UaClient client = new UaClient("opc.tcp://localhost:4840/Gateway-1");
        ReadTag(client, "ns=2;s=Main.dummyCntr").Wait();
        client.Disconnect();
    }

}


public class UaClient
{
    private Opc.Ua.ApplicationConfiguration _config;
    private Session? _session;
    private string _endpointUrl;
    private EndpointDescription? _selectedEndpoint = null;
    private string _dbgStr = "";

    public UaClient(string endpointUrl)
    {
        _endpointUrl = endpointUrl;
        _config = new Opc.Ua.ApplicationConfiguration
        {
            ApplicationName = "POC_CodesysHelloWorld",
            ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
            SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration 
            { 
                ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier
                { 
                    StoreType = @"Directory", 
                    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", 
                    SubjectName = "POC_CodesysHelloWorld"
                },
                TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList 
                { 
                    StoreType = @"Directory", 
                    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" 
                },
                TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList 
                { 
                    StoreType = @"Directory", 
                    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" 
                },
                RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList 
                { 
                    StoreType = @"Directory", 
                    StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" 
                },
                AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true
            },
            TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
            TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
            ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 },
            TraceConfiguration = new TraceConfiguration(),
            CertificateValidator = new CertificateValidator() { AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates= true }
        };
        _config.Validate(ApplicationType.Client).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (_config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates)
        {
            _config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += (s, e) => { e.Accept = e.Error.StatusCode == StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted; };
        }

        ApplicationInstance application = new ApplicationInstance
        {
            ApplicationName = "POC_CodesysHelloWorld",
            ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
            ApplicationConfiguration = _config
        };
        if (!application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            _dbgStr = "CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate returned false";
        }    
        try
        {
            _selectedEndpoint = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint(_endpointUrl, useSecurity: false, 15000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dbgStr = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
        EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create(_config);
        ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, _selectedEndpoint, endpointConfiguration);
        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = _config.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Certificate;
        ServiceMessageContext serviceMessageContext = _config.CreateMessageContext();
        ITransportChannel transportChannel = SessionChannel.Create(
            _config,
            UaClient.CreateEndpointDescription(clientCertificate),
            endpointConfiguration,
            clientCertificate,
            serviceMessageContext
            );
        try
        {
            _session = new Session(
                transportChannel,
                _config,
                endpoint,
                null
                );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dbgStr = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }

        try
        {
            //UserIdentity userIdentity = null;
            UserIdentity userIdentity = new UserIdentity();
            //UserIdentity userIdentity = new UserIdentity("doug", "Accip!23!23");
            _session.Open("My Session Name", userIdentity);

            if (_session != null && _session.Connected)
            {
                _dbgStr = "connected";
            }
            else
            {
                _dbgStr = "not connected";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _dbgStr = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (_session != null )
        {
            _session.Close();
            _session.Dispose();
            _session = null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<object> ReadNodeAsync(string nodeId)
    {
        if (_session == null) throw new Exception("Session is null");
        var node = new NodeId(nodeId);
        var dataValue = await _session.ReadValueAsync(node);
        return dataValue.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a minimal endpoint description which allows a client to connect to a server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// In most cases the client will use the server's discovery endpoint to fetch the information
    /// constained in this structure.
    /// </remarks>
    public static EndpointDescription CreateEndpointDescription(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        // create the endpoint description.
        EndpointDescription endpointDescription = new EndpointDescription();

        //endpointDescription.EndpointUrl = Utils.Format("http://{0}:61211/UA/SampleClient", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        endpointDescription.EndpointUrl = Utils.Format("opc.tcp://{0}:51210/UA/SampleServer", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        // endpointDescription.EndpointUrl = Utils.Format("http://{0}:51211/UA/SampleServer/None", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        // endpointDescription.EndpointUrl = Utils.Format("http://{0}:51211/UA/SampleServer", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());

        // specify the security policy to use.
        // endpointDescription.SecurityPolicyUri = SecurityPolicies.None;
        // endpointDescription.SecurityMode      = MessageSecurityMode.None;;
        endpointDescription.SecurityPolicyUri = SecurityPolicies.Basic256Sha256;
        endpointDescription.SecurityMode = MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt;

        // specify the transport profile.
        //endpointDescription.TransportProfileUri = Profiles.WsHttpXmlOrBinaryTransport;
        //endpointDescription.TransportProfileUri = Profiles.WsHttpXmlTransport;
        endpointDescription.TransportProfileUri = Profiles.UaTcpTransport;

        endpointDescription.Server.DiscoveryUrls.Add(Utils.Format("http://{0}:61211/UA/SampleClient/discovery", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()));

        // load the the server certificate from the local certificate store.
        CertificateIdentifier certificateIdentifier = new CertificateIdentifier();

        //certificateIdentifier.StoreType = CertificateStoreType.Windows;
        //certificateIdentifier.StoreType = CertificateStoreType.X509Store;
        certificateIdentifier.StoreType = CertificateStoreType.Directory;
        certificateIdentifier.StorePath = "LocalMachine\\My";
        certificateIdentifier.SubjectName = "UA Sample Client";

        X509Certificate2 serverCertificate = certificate;

        if (serverCertificate == null)
        {
            throw ServiceResultException.Create(StatusCodes.BadCertificateInvalid, "Could not find server certificate: {0}", certificateIdentifier.SubjectName);
        }

        endpointDescription.ServerCertificate = serverCertificate.RawData;

        return endpointDescription;
    }
}

